# Sort before group by

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by

There are 2 tables: mess_chats, mess_posts. I need to combine them on `chatID` column then sort by timestamp so newest posts are on top and finally group by `chatID`.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT   mess_chats.*, mess_posts.*
  FROM     mess_chats INNER JOIN mess_posts
           ON mess_chats.chatID = mess_posts.chatID
  WHERE    mess_chats.membersID="1"
  ORDER BY mess_posts.timestamp DESC
) AS tt
GROUP BY tt.chatID
```

Here is the error:

```
#1060 - Duplicate column name 'chatID'
```

EDIT:
I found solution and first I changed `mess_posts.chatID` column name to `mess_posts.pchatID` then sql code to:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT   mess_chats.*, mess_posts.*
  FROM     mess_chats JOIN mess_posts
           ON mess_chats.chatID = mess_posts.pchatID
  WHERE    mess_chats.membersID="1"
  ORDER BY mess_posts.timestamp DESC
) AS tt
GROUP BY tt.pchatID
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an order by before group by ,the results returned by using group by are indeterminate this can't guarantee  you  to give the most recent chat for the post, but here is way you can do that ,use a self join for `mess_chats` table on the chatid plus on the maximum time stamps

```
SELECT 
    c.*,
    p.* 
  FROM
    mess_chats c
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT chatID, MAX(`timestamp`) `timestamp` 
       FROM mess_chats GROUP BY chatID ) mc
      ON(c.chatID = mc.chatID AND c.`timestamp` = mc.`timestamp`)
    INNER JOIN mess_posts p 
      ON c.chatID = p.chatID 
  WHERE c.membersID = "1" 
  ORDER BY p.timestamp DESC
```

For the error in your query i would say you have `chatID` column with same name in both table so when you do a sub select and in group you refer tt.chatID then there are two columns in the result with `chatID` so you see the duplicate column name error, to over come this you need to give different alias for one the column

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT   mess_chats.*, mess_posts.*, mess_posts.chatID as 'post_chatID'
    FROM     mess_chats INNER JOIN mess_posts
        ON mess_chats.chatID = mess_posts.chatID
    WHERE    mess_chats.membersID="1"
    ORDER BY mess_posts.timestamp DESC
) AS tt
GROUP BY tt.post_chatID
```